# Searching for the highest determinant in a set of size (n choose k)

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, determinants

I have `n` row vectors and I can choose `k` vectors to form a `k*k` matrix.  Then I take the absolute value of the determinant of each matrix.  Therefore, I have `(n choose k)` possible absolute-value determinants.

I wish to choose the row vectors that yield the highest determinant.  Is it possible to optimize the search to do this quickly?

I am currently working with `n ~= 10,000` and `k = 31`, but I will be working with various setups.

I code in python and c++

Comment: This is one of the hardest optimization problems i saw on SO. Are you sure, that there is no other way in your application? It's just a feeling, but i'm pretty sure, that this problem is **np-complete** and even worse (negative approximation results). Even worse: constraining the ```k*k``` matrix to be semidefinite and approach it with convex optimization problems is also not working, because there is not much software available (you need to combine SDP + Integers). The only software i know of, which is able to do that, is [scip-sdp](http://www.opt.tu-darmstadt.de/~smars/scip_sdp.html).

Comment: SDP alone (no integers) is also very hard to solve (even if it's doable in polynomial-time; it will take a lot of time if it's not crashing due to numerical problems). Adding integers will call for trouble.

Comment: Yes, I must search the space of possible matrices to find the highest determinant.  I have assumed that there is no good way to find the highest determinants by studying the relationship between the vectors since they have complicated mathematical relationships with each other and are difficult to describe.  I believe that it may be even more complicated than the question I have asked.

Comment: The solution must be among the convex hull corners of your n vectors because the determinant is the signed volume of simplex spanned by the matrix row or column vectors and for any simplex with a vertex inside the convex hull there must be a greater simplex with all vertices on convex hull containing the first simplex. It can be that the convex hull of your vectors "most of the time" has significantly less corners.